# Unable to access Jekyll after sudo gem install

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Initially I wasn't able to install the gem through this.

```
$ gem install jekyll 
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/cache/fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem
```

Then some guides recommended using sudo so I used that

```
$ sudo gem install jekyll
```

which says it installed but then...

```
Successfully installed jekyll-2.5.3
Parsing documentation for jekyll-2.5.3
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

$ jekyll -v

/Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 105 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
from /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
from /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I'm guessing that by running the sudo install version, there's a different command or path that I need in order to access the gem? Or maybe the location that it's installed in is not recognized by whatever is trying to execute it?

I've looked up other cases where others have had issues with installing Jekyll and came across some research that I couldn't really understand.
So in case this information is needed to investigate my problem...

Currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

```
echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/shims:/Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/vincentchin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
 - /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
 - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
 - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
 - /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/shims
 - /Users/vincentchin/.rbenv/shims
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin
 - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
 - /usr/local/rvm/bin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /usr/local/git/bin
 - /opt/sm/bin
 - /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
 - /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ruby versions, have a try:

```
bundle exec jekyll -v
```

Comment: I got this error

 `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Should I remove one of the versions? I'm using RVM so I thought that wouldn't matter.

Comment: You just need to change directories to your app, if you doesn't create app by jekyll, please run `jekyll new my-awesome-site` ,then `cd my-awesome-site`

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled everything (rvm and rbenv) and cleaned up any leftover files that the uninstall didn't get and reinstalled rvm stable with ruby.

From there I was able to install using

```
gem install jekyll
```

and everything was smooth sailing from there.

I guess at some point when I was starting out, I installed a bunch of stuff without knowing what they were for (rbenv and rvm, should only have one of the two).